# Invalidate LTPA token on Websphere

Tags: java, security, websphere, websphere-7, ltpa

I am working on Integration project not on web based project, deployed on WebSphere Application Server having version 7.0.0.39. As I am not working on web project, I cannot use `ibm_security_logout` for logout(invalidating ltpa token). So can any one suggest any other way to invalidate or delete ltpa token. I am working on Servlet version 2.5 and Java version 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

In Servlet 2.5 you can try to use `WSSecurityHelper.revokeSSOCookies(req, res);` See here for more details [Erase cookie in WebSphere- how to log out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27473251/3701228)